# Why this $.isFunction returns false?

Tags: jquery

I created a jquery function, but $.isFunction seems to always return false if the function name is inside a string.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.myTest = function() {
       return true;
    }
})( jQuery );

alert($.isFunction('$.myTest'));
```

Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JqCzH/).

Note : if I remove quotes (eg. `alert($.isFunction($.myTest));`, it works, but my function is inside a string.

## EDIT

This function name is inside a string because I create a plugin to make ajax from parameters inside the dom elements. For example :

```
        data-route="xxx.php"
        data-lock=".buttonsToLock"
        data-output="#outputContainer"
        data-callback-after="$.myTest"
```

But I am unable to check if `data-callback-after` is an existing function.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: why or how is your function inside a string. you should explain that

Comment: @Ninsuo Then you need to securely evaluate your string to the object value and use `$.isFunction()` for it.

Comment: as vision stated, if you test to see if a string is a function , its going to return false.

Comment: That is true but i was confused because in php there is is_function function that takes a string, and is_callable that takes an "object" representating a function. So $.isFunction is closer to is_callable in lphp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you trying to dynamically call functions / callbacks.

You should consider the following approach.

```
    (function( $ ) {
        window.myTest = function() {
           return true;
        }
    })( jQuery );

var data-route="xxx.php",
    data-lock=".buttonsToLock",
    data-output="#outputContainer",
    data-callback-after="myTest";

    // To run the function 
    window[data-callback-after]();

    // To test the function
    $.isFunction(window[data-callback-after]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should always pass an object to [`$.isFunction()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) method:

```
alert($.isFunction($.myTest));
```

Otherwise, you will always receive `false`, since *string is not a function* by default.

Comment: Please read the question from the beginning to the end... This does not answer me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Seems like a legit answer to me

Comment: Technically speaking, it does work with strings. It tells you that a string is not a function.

Comment: Sorry if my question was wrongly written, you are right in a way, but I was missing something with `$.isFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

Functions will be stored in `window` so you could try something like this:

```
$.isFunction(window['myTest']);
```

But, since you are using "namespaces" you need to do it like this:

```
$.isFunction(window['$']['myTest']);
```

Or you can use this function:

```
function isFunctionByName(functionName, context) {
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return $.isFunction(context[func]);
}

alert(isFunctionByName("$.myTest", window));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqCzH/2/